# How do you declare a global constant in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some heavy calculations that I want to do when my program starts, and then I want to save the result (a big bumpy matrix) in memory so that I can use it again and again. My program contains multiple files and classes, and I would like to be able to access this variable from anywhere, and if possible define it as constant.

How do you define a global constant in Python?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just declare a variable on the module level and use it in the module as a global variable. And then you can also import it to other modules.

```
#mymodule.py
GLOBAL_VAR = 'Magic String' #or matrix...

def myfunc():
    print(GLOBAL_VAR)
```

And in other modules:

```
from mymodule import GLOBAL_VAR
```

Comment: You don't need 'global GLOBAL_VAR' to read the constant.  And you shouldn't be writing to it from in the function anyway (otherwise it's not a constant)

Answer (score 37):

I do not think the marked as good answer solves the op question. The `global` keyword in Python is used to modify a global variable in a local context ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)). This means that if the op **modifies** `SOME_CONSTANT` within `myfunc` the change will affect also **outside** the function scope (globally).

Not using the `global` keyword at the begining of `myfunc` is closer to the sense of *global constant* than the one suggested. Despite there are no means to render a value constant or immutable in Python.

Comment: What is a "variable constant"?

Comment: @Tripp it's not variable constant, it's constant variable. I.e.  a variable that cannot be changed. For example 'const int x=3;' in C++ declares a variable x that is equal to 3 and will never be changed.

Comment: Ah.  I was having trouble parsing the last sentence.  I will edit it for clarification.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to declare a constant in Python. You can just use

```
SOME_CONSTANT = [...]
```

If the file name where it is declared is `file1.py`, then you can access to it from other files in the following way:

```
import file1

print file1.SOME_CONSTANT
```

Assuming that both files are in the same directory.

Comment: what if they are not in the same directory? does one import them in some way?

Comment: I like this solution better than using `global` because less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'global constant'; because there are no constants in Python (there is no "data protection", all variables are accessible).

You can implement a [singleton pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Singleton.html), but you will have to regenerate this at runtime *each time*.

Your other option will be to store the results in an external store (like say, redis) which is accessible from all processes.

Depending on how big your data set is, storing it externally in a fast K/V like redis might offer a performance boost as well.

You would still have to transform and load it though, since redis would not know what a numpy array is (although it has [many complex types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) that you can exploit).

Answer (score 0):

An alternate is to import the constant directly from your constants file.

**Option 1**

*globals.py*

```
MY_CONSTANT = "Some constant value"
```

*main.py*

```
from globals import MY_CONSTANT

print(MY_CONSTANT)
```

**Option 2**

*globals.py*

```
MY_CONSTANT = "Some constant value"
```

*main.py*

```
import globals

print(globals.MY_CONSTANT)
```

So there are options on whether you're importing a bunch of constants in your file (option 2) is better or just a single constant (I prefer option 1).